# How can I sort a list comparing two fields?

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting

I have an object with a field that is distance, it can be in meters or kilo-meters, what I want to do is, sort that list first by meters and then by kilo-meters, so the meters are the first one in the list and then sort the kilo-meters. I used to do this with a `Comparator` but I don't know how to estructure this case.

What I used to do is a class that returns a comparator something like this :

```java
class WhateverComparator {

    fun getComparator() = compareBy<Whatever>({
        when (it.status) {
            is Whatever.Locked -> FIRST_POSITION
            is Whatever.FinishToday -> SECOND_POSITION
            is Whatever.DaysToExpire -> THIRD_POSITION
        }
    }, { it.discount })

    companion object {
        private const val FIRST_POSITION = 0
        private const val SECOND_POSITION = 1
        private const val THIRD_POSITION = 2
    }
}
```

and it worked, but now I don't know how to estructure the object to have this distance, I thought about creating a `sealed class` named `DistanceInfo` where it can be

```java
data class Meters(val value:Float, val symbol: String):DistanceInfo()
```

and also

```java
data class KiloMeters(val value:Float, val symbol: String):DistanceInfo()
```

but I'm not succeeding.

The thing is that I have this `symbol` because it's translated by country, so it's not always "KM", that's why I need to have the `symbol`.

Any idea?

### Edit

My class is :

```
data class Store(val id: String, val name: String, val distanceFormatted: String, val distanceNumber: Float, val distanceSymbol: String)
```

Also thinking another way to re-estructure this class to don't be like this.

DistanceFormatted ie: 34,38 Meters or 19,21 Kilometers
DistanceNumber ie : 23,13
DistanceSymbol ie : Meters/Kilometers/km/m

Comment: What data are you working with? I also believe the question needs more focus. The title and first part talks about sorting, but after you talk about how to structure your data?  Which is it? I believe how to sort you already figured out, and this question is really about data structures. All the text about sorting is cluttering the real problem I believe, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Ivo already edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
class StoreComparator {

    fun getComparator() = compareBy<Store>({
        if (it.distanceFormatted.lowercase().contains("kilo")) SECOND_POSITION else FIRST_POSITION
    }, { it.distanceNumber })

    companion object {
        private const val FIRST_POSITION = 0
        private const val SECOND_POSITION = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong he told that the `distanceFormatted` could be any word so making this `contains` won't work for all...

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yeah I wasn't entirely sure about that. If that's the case then there isn't really a solution I guess unless you know exactly which words are possible

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you "standardize" the `value` in `Meters` and then convert it to `Kilometers` or else if needed.

```kotlin
data class Meters(val value:Float, val symbol: String) {
  fun toKilometers() : Kilometers = Kilometers(value = this.value / 1000f, symbol = "km")
  
  // if needed
  fun toCentimeters() : Centimeters= Centimeters(value = this.value * 100f, symbol = "cm")
}
```

So, when you want to sort it , you just need to sort it by the `value`.